# Query on a relation table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have  a relation table with this data. What I want is a query which returns an `a_id` to which every connected `status` equals 1.

So in this case, 6 would be the value returned.

```
a_id b_id status
4     757   0
4     758   0
4     761   0
5     757   1
5     758   0
5     761   1
6     757   1
6     761   1
6     758   1
```

MySQL 5.5

Comment: And where's your effort?

Comment: @shree.pat18 I tried with `group by` and `order by`, but since this is the only order they can be written in, my idea of ordering the rows by `status` then grouping by `a_id` didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a_id
FROM relation_table
WHERE a_id NOT IN (SELECT a_id FROM relation_table WHERE status != 1);
```

Comment: That would return 5 as well.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha No, this seems to work, because 5 has at least one row with 0 `status`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT a_id
FROM table1
WHERE a_id NOT IN
    (SELECT a_id
     FROM table1
     WHERE status != 1);
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4dde17/2)

Answer (score -1):

SELECT DISTINCT a_id
FROM table_name
WHERE a_id NOT IN (SELECT a_id FROM table_name WHERE status = 0);

Reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_distinct

Comment: That would return 5 as well.